# How to get cookie value and also time stamp in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, timestamp

I want to assign time stamp in set cookie and need to get it in get cookie.Here I tried to set key-value pair in set cookie and I get that value in get cookie.It works fine for me .But I want to set time stamp in set cookie.I would like to get time stamp in get cookie using javascript.
Thanks in advance

```js
function tick(){
    var username="time_tick";
    setCookie("name", username);
}

function setCookie(name,value) {
    alert ("set");
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (50*1000));
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = name + "="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    alert(document.cookie);
}

function idletimmer(){
    t = setTimeout(idletimmer, 1000000);//10 second
    getCookie(name);
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var read_cookies = document.cookie;
    var split_read_cookie = read_cookies.split(";");
    alert(read_cookies);
    for (i=0;i<split_read_cookie.length;i++){
        var value=split_read_cookie[i];
        value=value.split("=");
        if(value[i]=="time_tick"){
            alert('it is 1');
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Set cookie" onclick="tick()">

<input type="button" value="get cookie" onclick="idletimmer()">
```